# SRID of geoemtry exported in PostgreSQL with ogr2ogr

Tags: postgis, ogr2ogr, srid

I use ogr2ogr to export geometric data from EDIGEO files to some PostgreSQL table in append mode, but the output geometry SRID is always set to zero.

Can I do something to specify the output geometry SRID ?

the command I use is :

```
ogr2ogr -append -dialect SQLITE -f Postgresql PG:"dbname=test
port='5434' user='postgres' active_schema=napo"  thefile.thf
-sql "SELECT cast(commune_id.idu as smallint) AS insee ,section_id.tex AS section,
parcelle_id.tex AS numero,setsrid(parcelle_id.geometry,3942) AS geom,
setsrid(parcelle_id_label.geometry,3942) AS point 
FROM commune_id 
LEFT JOIN section_id ON section_id.idu = section_id.idu
LEFT JOIN parcelle_id ON parcelle_id.idu = parcelle_id.idu left join
LEFT JOIN parcelle_id_label ON parcelle_id.object_rid = parcelle_id_label.ogr_obj_lnk"
-nln napo -a_srs EPSG:3942 -s_srs EPSG:3942
```

The table is created by the first call of the command.

Comment: Show your whole ogr2ogr command and tell us how the table was initially created.

Comment: If you're doing `ogr2ogr` on append mode shouldn't SRID conform to SRID of geometry column? Table def and `ogr2ogr` statement would be helpful.

Comment: OK, it is done !